# CS7036: No argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter

Tags: c#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class OblstacleMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Obstacle;
    public int velocidad;
    private int VelocidadRotacion;
    public 
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        velocidad = 3;
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (gameObject.tag == "Vertical")
        {
            Obstacle.transform.Rotate(1, 0, 0, Space.Self);
        }
        if (gameObject.tag == "Horizontal")
        {
            Obstacle.transform.Rotate(0, 0, 1, Space.Self);
        }
        if(gameObject.tag == "Cube")
        {
            transform.Translate(new Vector2(velocidad * Time.deltaTime, 0));
            ChangeDirection();
        }

        //Obstacle.transform.Rotate(0, 0, 1, Space.Self);
    }

    public void ChangeDirection(Collision collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.tag == "MapLimit")
        {
            velocidad = velocidad * -1;
        }
    }
}
```

i get this error:

Assets\Scripts\OblstacleMove.cs(30,13): error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'collision' of 'OblstacleMove.CambioDireccion(Collision)'

i tryed

```
if(gameObject.tag == "Cube")
        {
            transform.Translate(new Vector2(velocidad * Time.deltaTime, 0));
            CambioDireccion(Collision collision);
        }
```

and it didnt work, i also tryed

```
    private void ChangeDirection(Collision collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.tag == "MapLimit")
        {
            velocidad = velocidad * -1;
        }
    }
```

i dont know what else to try

Comment: Side note; I thoguht this must surely be a duplicate, but a cursory look only found questions about constructors/the failure to appreciate that C# provides invisible default constructors etc - I didn't feel that anything that I reviewed contained targeted enough advice that it would be easily cross-applicable for the level of understanding demonstrated. Duplicate suggestions would still be welcome

Comment: The global class, or the script of the target class is empty and does not exist. Usually, the original project project is packaged with .unitypackage and imported into the new project, and then the script containing the target class is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you declare a method to take 1 parameter:

```
private void CambioDireccion(Collision collision)
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                         1 parameter, of type Collision
```

You have to provide 1 argument (value for the parameter) when you call it. You cannot call it with 0 arguments like you have done:

```
CambioDireccion();
               ^^
         0 arguments provided
```

Either provide 1 argument when you call it, or modify the method to accept 0 parameters, or change the parameter to be optional so it can be called with either 0 or 1 arguments:

```
CambioDireccion(...);                                   //calling the method providing an argument. Replace ... with some relevant instance of a Collision object. This is the most likely resolution
private void CambioDireccion(){                         //modify the method to accept 0 parameters. This will likely fail because the method body uses the passed-in argument
private void CambioDireccion(Collision collision = ...) //modify the method so the parameter is optional; provide a sensible default in place of `...`. Often this is `null`. The method body would have to be modified in some way to work for the case where the optional element was leveraged; perhaps checking for null and responding differently
```

You have to decide what the most logical course of action is from these options. It's probably going to be to provide a Collision object, something like:

```
Collision c = ... //get a Collision from somewhere or make one
CambioDireccion(c);
```

When you call a method and provide arguments, you dont specify the type, just the name of the variable that is the type, or the name of a method that returns an instance of the type, or a call to make a new one of the type (which may include property initializers):

```
CambioDireccion(variableThatIsACollision);
CambioDireccion(MethodThatReturnsACollision());
CambioDireccion(new Collision());
CambioDireccion(new Collision() { Prop1 = Value1, Prop2 = Value2 });
```

Comment: Such a nice Visual Studio imitation :P

Comment: what do you mean by 1 parameter? if i do it like `private void CambioDireccion(Collision)` it gives me more errors.

Comment: Collision is a type. You need to provide an instance of the type

Comment: also how can i modify it to accept it with 0 parameters?

Comment: can you upload the solution cause im new to unity and i dont fully understand the terms

Comment: The problem is that you have a very limited understanding of C#; you're desperately trying to get the error to go away, but it's likely that most things you try will lead to more errors. You need to sit and think about what is the *most logical* course of action. There isn't a solution I can give you, because I don't know what your overall intent is.

Comment: @HackerDragon You can remove the parameter - so the signature would be `private void CambioDireccion()` - but then your code wouldn't compile as it checks the value of the `collision` object. But you don't seem to have one to pass.

Comment: thanks to everyone i already solved it. I deleted the void ChangeDirection and made  `private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)`
 `   {`
        `if(gameObject.CompareTag("Cubo"))`
        `{`
            `if (collision.gameObject.tag == "MapLimit")`
            `{`
                `velocidad = velocidad * -1;`
            `}`
        `}`
    `}`

Comment: @HackerDragon glad it's fixed, but that looks like the same code with a different method name. I don't really see how it can have fixed the problem.

Comment: @Charles I wondered if maybe it's made an event handler, and it has hence become the responsibility of something else to call the method and supply the collision

Comment: @CaiusJard funny you should say that, I just googled and [came to the same conclusion](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter.html). I guess the fix is to no longer attempt to call it. Not very familiar with Unity!

Answer (score 0):

Just remove "ChangeDirection();" from Update and change its name to "OnCollisionEnter", these names are important because these are Unity Messages that are being invoked when certain things in game happen. So basicly you want to wait for CollisionEnter message and then check tag and change direction. (Press Ctrl + Shift + M in VS to see all available messages)